# What is the best way to pull miner's fee associated with a list of transactions?

Tags: blockchain, transaction-fees, blockexplorer

I have a spreadsheet containing the transaction ID, datetime, and BTC amount of 800,000+ transactions associated with a BTC address (includes both sent and received transactions). Now I am trying to add another column listing the fee paid for each of those transactions. What is the (1) fastest (2) easiest (3) most efficient way to do that? Please explain in detail if technical know-how is required, because I am a novice in coding.

Comment: You can calculate it using `vin` and `vout` from `getrawtransaction` if using Bitcoin Core but it won't be easy to using API for an open source block explorer like https://mempool.space will be a better approach

Comment: @Prayank not entirely. `vin` only contains the prevouts so you'd have to  call `getrawtransaction` again. Also, it won't work without `txindex`.

Comment: @darosior Correct. I wanted to write in short so ignored those details and suggested using https://mempool.space API instead